# Why is my asynchronous input undefined in useEffect?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm writing a React application that fetches image data from a server for an array of URLs. I am storing the camera images as large strings that are placed into the image's src attribute. I am using `useReducer` to store my dictionary of camera objects.

I am having a couple of problems getting the reducer to work, and one of them has to do with some confusion I'm having with asynchronous values and why the async function returns correct output but the completion handler (.then()) receives undefined as a result.

Here is the code for useEffect() and the asynchronous fetching function.

`useEffect()`

```
    //Why is cameras undefined?
    useEffect(() => {
        if (phase === 0) {
            let cameras = {}
            getCameraInformation().then((cameras) => {
                debugger;
                dispatch({
                    type: 'loadedCameraInformation',
                    payload: {cameras: cameras}
                });
            }).finally(() => setPhase(1))
        }
    });
```

My function signature and variables:

```
export default function Main() {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cameraReducer, initialState);
    let [phase, setPhase] = useState(0);
```

My function for `getCameraInformation`:
This returns a dictionary full of correct information!

```js
async function getCameraInformation() {
  //returns a json with the following: url, cam_name, cam_pass, cam_user, channel, chunk, group, path, port,
  // uptime, username.

  let cam_json = await axios
    .get(getCamerasURL, { headers: { auth: get_cookie("token") } })
    .then(response => {
      let tempCameraArray = response.data.body;
      let tempCameraDictionary = {};

      for (var camera in tempCameraArray) {
        tempCameraDictionary[tempCameraArray[camera].sid] = {
          cameraInformation: tempCameraArray[camera],
          cameraImage: null
        };
      }

      return tempCameraDictionary;
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

Comment: First thing I've noticed is that in `useEffect` you define `cameras`, but then also take `cameras` as an argument to `.then`, so you've essentially got two `cameras` variables. Does renaming one of them fix anything?

Comment: It is shadowing, but in that case he'd expect neither of those variables to be `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I did have cameras, above, but even after removing it it is still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `async function getCameraInformation` doesn't have a `return` statement, so its promise will not resolve any value. There is a `return` in the `then` callback, but that's a different function entirely.

You are also using `await` and `then()` on the same promise, which isn't ideal. Use one or the other, because it's very easy to get confused when you mix and match here.

You already have an `async`, so don't use `then` at all in side that function.

```
async function getCameraInformation() {
  //returns a json with the following: url, cam_name, cam_pass, cam_user, channel, chunk, group, path, port,
  // uptime, username.

  let response = await axios.get(getCamerasURL, { headers: { auth: get_cookie('token') } })
  let tempCameraArray = response.data.body
  let tempCameraDictionary = {}

  for (var camera in tempCameraArray) {
    tempCameraDictionary[tempCameraArray[camera].sid] = {
      cameraInformation: tempCameraArray[camera],
      cameraImage: null,
    }
  }

  return tempCameraDictionary
}
```

Comment: Hmm, getting rid of `then` and using only await seems to make me at least complete the first of two requests for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. And don't forget to upvote and accept answers if they solved your problem. Looks like you have a few questions without accepted answers over the last months. We answerers like our meaningless points! :)